# (LineageOS) Building android_packages_apps_<app name> on macOS (darwin)

Tags: android, android-source, cyanogenmod

I am trying to build individual apps packages from the LineageOS source code.

For this, I am using the following command to build Eleven for instance:

```
mmm packages/apps/Eleven
```

I get the following error:

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=7.1.1
LINEAGE_VERSION=14.1-20170212-UNOFFICIAL-bacon
TARGET_PRODUCT=lineage_bacon
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=krait
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-16.4.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
HOST_CROSS_OS=
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=NMF26V
OUT_DIR=/Volumes/SSD/android/system/out
============================================
Running kati to generate build-lineage_bacon-mmm-packages_apps_Eleven_Android.mk.ninja...
Environment variable BUILD_NUMBER was modified (07faf94a3d => cf0c1648ca), regenerating...
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=7.1.1
LINEAGE_VERSION=14.1-20170212-UNOFFICIAL-bacon
TARGET_PRODUCT=lineage_bacon
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=krait
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-16.4.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
HOST_CROSS_OS=
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=NMF26V
OUT_DIR=/Volumes/SSD/android/system/out
============================================
No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE bacon
Starting build with ninja
ninja: Entering directory `.'
ninja: error: '/Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/core-junit_intermediates/classes.dex.toc', needed by '/Volumes/SSD/android/system/out/target/common/obj/APPS/Eleven_intermediates/with-local/classes.dex', missing and no known rule to make it
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (15 seconds) ####
```

Is there a problem with the openjdk-8-jdk? I downloaded it from oracle as written in the build documentation for bacon.

I am on macOS sierra 10.12.3

Answer (score 0):

Try building with dependencies

```
mmma packages/apps/Eleven
```